# Keras: Obtain array of images and labels from flow_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to obtain a confusion matrix using scikit after training my model but since I used `flow_from_directory`, I don't have access to the data and labels or I don't know a way to do so. Since scikit confusion matrix method is used like:

```
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

and `flow_from_directory` doesn't return the true labels. Is there a way to obtain them from `flow_from_directory` directly or any other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any `generator`, you can yield data as with any iterable:

```
for x, y in something.flow_from_directory(...):
    #do stuff
```

Be careful to decide when to stop. Generators for training in keras are infinite.